# Conceptual meaning of 'not' keyword; evaluating between objects

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I am trying to find a `BucketTotal` object which has the smallest `total` in a Drools Planner project. I adapted this from example code.

```
rule "insertMinimumBucketTotal"
when
   $b : BucketTotal($total : total)
   not BucketTotal(total > $total) // CONFUSED HERE
then
   insertLogical(new MinimumBucketTotal($total));
end
```

As far as my reasoning went, it meant "find `BucketTotal` object `$b`, such that there doesnt exist another `BucketTotal` object whose `total` is **greater than** `total` of `$b`".

Turns out, it meant the opposite (and I corrected it).

---

Please explain how Drools reasons that statement to find `$b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed your are confusing things. "not" means "not exists". So if you want to find the minimum total you can do:

```
rule "minimum"
when
   BucketTotal( $min : total )
   not BucketTotal( total < $min )
then
   // do something with $min
end
```

The above is usually the more performant way of doing it, but you can also use accumulate if you prefer:

```
rule "minimum"
when
    accumulate( BucketTotal( $total : total ),
                $min : min( $total ) )
then
    // do something with $min
end
```